# Прошу оценить код генерации рандомных пришельцев

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет! На днях написал программу на python3 которая генерирует 10 пришельцев случайного вида. Всего видов два (красные и зеленые). Ну а после генерации выводит сколько пришельцев определенного вида сгенерировалось. Прошу оценить мой код, и если подобную функцию можно было написать гораздо проще, то буду благодарен если просветите))

```
import random

aliens = []
max_aliens = 10
red_aliens = 0

for alien_number in range(0, max_aliens):
    new_alien_1 = {'color': 'red', 'points': '10'}
    new_alien_2 = {'color': 'green', 'points': '5'}
    r_numb = random.randint(1, 2)
    if r_numb == 1:
        aliens.append(new_alien_1)
        red_aliens += 1
    else:
        aliens.append(new_alien_2)

for alien in aliens:
    print(alien)

print(f'\nRed aliens - {red_aliens}')
print(f'Green aliens - {max_aliens - red_aliens}')
```

Comment: опасную тему вы затеяли

Answer (score 1):

```
al_kinds = ({'color': 'red', 'points': '10'},{'color': 'green', 'points': '5'})    
for _ in range(max_aliens):
    t = random.randint(0,1)
    aliens.append(al_kinds[t]) 
    if t==0:  
        red_aliens += 1
```

Без подсчета красных можно сделать однострочник с генератором списка

Comment: Лучше использовать [`random.getrandbits(1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.getrandbits), работает в 6 раз быстрее чем `randint`.

Answer (score 1):

как вариант

```
import random

aliens = []
max_aliens = 10
red_aliens = 0
new_aliens = [{'color': 'red', 'points': '10'}, {'color': 'green', 'points': '5'}]
for alien_number in range(max_aliens) :
    r = random.choice(new_aliens)
    if r == new_aliens[0]:
        aliens.append(new_aliens[0])
        red_aliens += 1
    else:
        aliens.append(new_aliens[1])


for alien in aliens:
    print(alien)

print(f'\nRed aliens - {red_aliens}')
print(f'Green aliens - {max_aliens - red_aliens}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import secrets

aliens = []
max_aliens = 10

for a in range(max_aliens):
    born = Aliens()
    born.genetic_mutations()
    born.take_over_another_planet()
    aliens.append(born)

class Aliens():
    def __init__(self):
        color_ = ['red', 'green']
        self.color = secrets.choice(color_)
        self.points = 0

    def take_over_another_planet(self):
        print('%s alien sat in a starship and flight to destroy the earth' % (self.color))

    def genetic_mutations(self):
        self.points = 5
        if self.color == 'red':
            self.points = 10
```